# In a table how to select distinct values of one column by keeping reference of other column?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, where-clause

In my table i have CategoryID and ProductName, here CategoryID has duplicate values. How do i select ProductName with distinct categoryID?

I have tried stack overflow answers which appeared similar but none of them helped.

```
    +++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++
    + ProductName +  + CategoryID +
    +++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++
        Mac                1
        HP                 3
        Walker             1
        Bell               2
        Dell               4   
        Lenovo             3
        Pixel              2
```

The result should be

```
    +++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++
    + ProductName +  + CategoryID +
    +++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++
        Mac                1
        HP                 3 
        Bell               2
        Dell               4
```

Comment: What would the results be?  And what does "with distinct CategoryID" mean?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The result should contain ProductName with distinct CategoryID

Comment: Why Mac and not Walker?

Comment: @forpas that also fine. for representation purpose only i wrote Mac

Comment: @ghostdeathrider see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to `group by categoryid` and get the minimum (or maximum?) `productname`:

```
select categoryid, min(productname) as productname
from tablename
group by categoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for categories that contain only a single product.  If so, you can use aggregation:

```
select categoryid, max(productname) as productname
from t
group by categoryid;
```

Comment: i executed the above query, the result came blank.

Comment: if we remove last line, i.e, "having count(*) = 1;" result came as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Row_number with partition by. Here's the Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE  docs (
  ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  CategoryID int  NOT NULL
) ;
INSERT INTO docs (ProductName ,CategoryID ) VALUES
  ('Mac', 1),
  ('HP', 3),
  ('Walker', 1 ),
  ('Bell', 2 ),
  ('Dell', 4 ),
  ('Lenova', 3),
  ('Pixel', 2)
```

Then run using the foll. select query:

```
SELECT ProductName, CategoryID 
from(
SELECT CategoryID, ProductName, 
row_number() over (partition by CategoryID order by ProductName ) as rn
from docs ) tab
where rn = 1;
```

This returns the output as

```
+++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++
+ ProductName +  + CategoryID +
+++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++
    Mac                1
    Bell               2
    HP                 3 
    Dell               4
```